# Linux CentOS 6 how to setup proxy for all protocols

Tags: linux, proxy

I have 2 CentOS 6 with a proxy in between

I have set the proxy for http and ftp in ~/.bash_profile/bashrc and it works fine but if I use a different protocol it doesn't work ( obviously ), a simple telnet perhaps fails

Anyone knows how I could setup proxy settings for all the protocols ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Proxychains for this.

```
http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/
```

First install proxychains and then configure your proxy settings in /etc/proxychains.conf file.

Add at last, these lines for HTTP and HTTPS proxy.

```
http    proxy-ip   proxy-port    username        password
https   proxy-ip   proxy-port    username        password
```

Now you can do telnet by using the following command:

```
$ proxychains telnet www.google.com 3128
```